# Can I use Rules Transform to remove text from a returned value?

Tags: 7, rules

I notice that Drupal [Rules Data Transforms](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_data_transforms) has the "trim text" action option. Is it possible to trim the returned value by a specific number of characters, or remove a specific word from the returned string?

**E.g.** I grab an entity field value with my first action, and I want to remove the word "grams" from the returned value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try applying this Rules Data Transforms [replace text patch](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_data_transforms/issues/2452931) which adds the ability to replace text. Flush cache after applying patch.

So now simply replace grams with nothing (empty).

Comment: I applied the patch succesfully, and it provides the action 'replace text'. However when I select it, I get an empty screen and the error 'Unknown action replace_text'.

Comment: @Brittany Did you flush your cache after applying the patch?